# What did The 13th Doctor say?

Tags: doctor-who

Jodie Whittaker made her first appearance as The Doctor this evening, uttering one line before

> apparently causing multiple systems failures in the TARDIS and being ejected therefrom.

I found the line unintelligible. Did anyone understand it?

Comment: Something about poor ratings and the need to get a new writing team.

Comment: I heard "Oh, Berlin!" which seemed like a catchphrase of old Doctors, so I liked it.. I want it to remain that way.. :)

Comment: Lots of planets have a north.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The official subtitle on BBC iPlayer reads

> "Oh, brilliant!"

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I heard

Comment: @HorusKol - The official subtitles, especially on a broadcast as high-profile as this, would come directly from the makers rather than being transcribed from the episode.

Comment: I know - I meant more that it sounded pretty clear to me what she said.